# Laravel 5 Eloquent relationship: can't modify/overwrite relationship table property

Tags: php

I am using Laravel 5's `belongsToMany` method to define related tables using an intermediary pivot table. My application is using the eloquent models **Tour** and **TourCategory**. In the Tour Model I have:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tour extends Model
{
    public function cats(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\TourCategory', 'tour_cat_assignments', 'tour_id', 'cat_id');
    }

}
```

In my controller I am retrieving all the data from the tour table along with the associated category data using Laravel's `with` method:

```
$tours = Tour::with('cats')->get();
```

That all works fine. The problem is that I don't want the category data in its current raw form, I need to first rearrange it. However I cannot overwrite the `cats` property without unsetting it first:

```
public function serveTourData(){

    $tours = Tour::with('sections', 'cats')->get();

    foreach($tours as $tour){

        unset($tour->cats); // If I unset first, then it respects the new value. Why do I need to do this?

        $tour->cats = "SOME NEW VALUE";
    }

    Log::info($tours);
}
```

Can someone explain the logic behind this please?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: I think this is actually just a feature of how php's `foreach` method works. I can't remember, but I probably just stuck with unsetting first, as per the above code.

Comment: yep I do the same. Anyway thanks

Comment: I was also looking for a solution. Used the unset workaround although not really satisfied with it :-(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To override relations on some model, you can use:

```
public function serveTourData(){

$tours = Tour::with('sections', 'cats')->get();

foreach($tours as $tour){
    $tour->setRelation('cats', "SOME NEW VALUE");
}

Log::info($tours);
```

}

[For laravel 5.4 -  setRelation](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_setRelation)

Of course if you are using laravel >= 5.6, you can unset relations by [unsetRelation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L715)

Comment: Thank you so much. That save me.

Comment: Helped me with during an hour struggle, thank you!

Comment: Am using 5.5, this works and logs as you said but IDKY when I send the response back via `response()->json()` it doesn't show my relation at all, let alone the array that I set.

Comment: Will be good to see your code @DaniyalNasir