# Eloquent relationship in Laravel 6. Can't modify/overwrite relationship attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I built a one to one relationship between two Eloquent models and I want to replace an relationship attribute called `profile_picture` inside my `User` Eloquent model but I don't know how to do it.

This is a summary of my `User` model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject{

    use Notifiable;

    public function profile_picture(){
        return $this->hasOne(UserProfilePicture::class);
    }
}
```

And this is a summary of my `UserProfilePicture` model.

```
class UserProfilePicture extends Model{

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

This is how I pretent to do it in my `UserController` file.

```
public function publicUserData($username){

    $user = User::where("username", $username)->with("profile_picture")->first();

    if($user){
        if(!$user->profile_picture){
            $user->profile_picture = UserProfilePicture::$defaultUserProfilePicture;
        }
        return response()->json($user);
    }

    return response()->json(false);
}
```

This is `$defaultUserProfilePicture` static array.

```
public static $defaultUserProfilePicture = [
    "url" => "public/avatars/defaultUserPhoto.jpg",
    "size" => 5229
];
```

I tried to use mutators but looks like it isn't work on relationships attributes.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908598/laravel-5-eloquent-relationship-cant-modify-overwrite-relationship-table-prope) but doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesnt `setRelation` work for you? As in, `$user->setRelation('profile_pic', UserProfilePi...::$default)`

Comment: I don't even try with that, that exists in Laravel 6 ?, I can't find it in Laravel Docs !

Comment: It's available https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_setRelation

Comment: It's not working, $user->setRelation("profile_picture", UserProfilePicture::$defaultUserProfilePicture); ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provides the relation default model with attributes, you may pass an array or Closure to the `withDefault` method

```php
public function profile_picture(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfilePicture::class)->withDefault(UserProfilePicture::$defaultUserProfilePicture);
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, first I put the static array `UserProfilePicture::$defaultUserProfilePicture` into my database then I do:

```
$user->setRelation("profile_picture", UserProfilePicture::find(1));
```

That take one more database request but is the one solution to I have for now.

Comment: if you only want this entity to have those 2 attributes you can do that without a trip to the database, assuming those 2 fields are fillable: `UserProfilePicture::make( $thatArray )` then you will have an instance with those attributes